# Add Data to post on facebook wall in android not displaying any message to post

Tags: android, facebook

I am using the following code and trying to post message on facebook wall along with the picture url. Both message and picture url is empty. Can any one find out and direct me in the right direction?

```
btnPostToWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            postToWall();
        }
    });


public void postToWall() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();

    params.putString("message","test to post");

    params.putString("url", URLEncoder.encode("http://a.espncdn.com/photo/2010/0523/pg2_a_cricket_576.jpg"));

    try {
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // post on user's wall.
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: so is it post your code on wall ?

Comment: no it is not posting @chintankhetiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set this **permission** as public

```
private String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]

    { "publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access" };
```

This will check is session exist if yes then it will direct update if not then ask user permission to update on wall.

Button **click event**

```
    facebookConnector = new FacebookConnector(APP_ID, activity.getParent(), 
activity.getApplicationContext(),PERMISSIONS);
    if (facebookConnector.getFacebook().isSessionValid())
    {   
         postMessageInThread(position); // see method below 
    }
    else
    {
         SessionEvents.AuthListener listener = new SessionEvents.AuthListener()
    {

@Override
public void onAuthSucceed()
{
     postMessageInThread(position);
}

@Override
public void onAuthFail(String error)
{
}
};  

SessionEvents.addAuthListener(listener);
    facebookConnector.login();
}
```

This will update your data on wall

```
private void postMessageInThread(final int position)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    facebookConnector.postMessageOnWall(
                            "Your Text Data",
                            "Your Email URL","Description");
                    mFacebookHandler.post(mUpdateFacebookNotification);
                } catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.e("", "Error sending msg", ex);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
```

**Note:** : Here Position is my list record so manage your data according to that.